# Monomorphism between two ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I $ and $J $ be two ideals in a commutative ring $R $ with $1$. Is there any equivalent property for the fact  that there are no $R $-module **monomorphism** from $I $ to $J $?

Comment: Assume that $R$ is regular.  Then every ideal $I$ equals $I_D I_N$ where $I_D$ is an ideal that is an invertible sheaf, and where $I_N$ is an ideal of coheight $\geq 2$.  Then there exists a monomorphism fro $I$ to $J$ only if $I_N$ is contained in $J_N$ as ideals of $R$, and this is still true after localization.  Conversely, if $I_N$ is contained in $J_N$, then every prime ideal is contained in a localization $R'$ such that $I\otimes_R R'$ admits a monomorphism to $J\otimes_R R'$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... Suppose $R$ is a domain and $J$ is not zero. Choose any non-zero element $x\in J$, and consider multiplication by $x$. Wouldn't that be a monomorphism $I\to J$ for any $I$?

Comment: More generally, if $J$ contains any nonzerodivisor $x$ then multiplication by $x$ gives a monomorphism into $J$. So if there are to be no such monomorphisms then a necessary (but probably not sufficient?) condition is that every element of $J$ must be a zerodivisor, i.e., $J$ must be contained in a minimal prime of $R$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Actually there can be ideals of positive height that consist of zerodivisors.  For instance in $R=k[x,y]/(x^2, xy)$, $J = (x,y)$ is a non-minimal prime but consists of zero-divisors.

Comment: Oh dear. The set of zerodivisors is a union of prime ideals (cf Atiyah-Macdonald exercise I.14 on pg 12) but not necessarily a union of minimal primes! I misremembered. Sorry. Thanks @NeilEpstein.

I maintain that a necessary condition for $J$ to have no such monomorphisms is for $J$ to consist of zerodivisors. But it doesn't imply $J$ is contained in a prime ideal. (The set of zerodivisors is a union of primes but maybe not a finite union, so I can't use prime avoidance.)

Comment: @ZachTeitler Actually if $R$ is Noetherian, then the set of zero divisors is a finite union -- namely the union of the associated primes of $R$ (i.e. the prime ideals that are the radicals of an irredundant primary decomposition of the zero ideal).  You are certainly right that if $J$ contains a regular element, then there is a monomorphism from the unit ideal to $J$, hence from any ideal to $J$. So in the Noetherian case, $J$ needs to be contained in an associated prime of the ring. I'm as puzzled as you on finding better conditions though.